# Making shared pointer point to new instance

Tags: c++, sfml, smart-pointers

So I have an Abstract base class `BaseScreen` and a child class `MainMenu` (and a few others).
Then I create a smart pointer `std::shared_ptr<BaseScreen> CurrentScreen`.  However, when I try to do something like this:

`CurrentScreen = std::make_shared<rpg::MainMenu>(new rpg::MainMenu());`

I get error C2664. I am still fairly new to smart pointers and I tried to research why I was getting this error, but I couldn't find anything related to this error and smart pointers. (Though I do have a general idea as to why the error itself occurs.)

Here is the code in case it is needed:

```
class BaseScreen : public sf::Drawable
{  
public:
    virtual void HandleEvents(sf::RenderWindow& screen, sf::Event events) = 0;

    BaseScreen(){}
    virtual ~BaseScreen(){}

};
```

...

```
class MainMenu : public BaseScreen
{
private:
    ButtonComponent myStartButton;

public:

    virtual void HandleEvents(sf::RenderWindow& screen, sf::Event events){}

    MainMenu(){}
    ~MainMenu(){}

private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

...

```
class Screens : public sf::Drawable
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseScreen> myScreen;

public:
    Screens() 
    {
        //error C2664
        myScreen = std::make_shared<rpg::MainMenu>(new rpg::MainMenu());
    }
    ~Screens(){}

private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the text of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::make_shared` constructs the object itself. The arguments you should pass to it are the arguments you want to pass to the object's constructor. If you want the object to be default-constructed, then:

```
CurrentScreen = std::make_shared<rpg::MainMenu>();
```

If you pass `new rpg::MainMenu()` to `std::make_shared`, then it attempts to pass this pointer---of type `rpg::MainMenu*`---to the constructor of `rpg::MainMenu`, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Ah, that makes a ton more sense. Thank you.